# How to factorize injection?

Tags: angularjs, jasmine

I've a unit test with 10 item function, all of them have an `inject` callback to a custom service:

```
describe('Something', function() {

    beforeEach(module('myApp'));

    it('Foo == bar ?', inject(function(ctrl) {
        expect(ctrl.foo).toEqual('Bar');
    }));

    // 10 other function with the same injection
});
```

Is there a way to factorize these injection into the `beaforeach` function?

Edit :

My *controller.js*:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp');

app.factory('ctrl', function(){
    return {'foo': 'Bar'};
});
```

Comment: Was the answer helpful?

Answer (score 2):

```
describe('Something', function() {
    var control;

    beforeEach(function() {
         module('myApp');

         inject(function(_ctrl_) {
             control = _ctrl_;
         });

         //or can use $injector
         /*inject(function($injector) {
             control = $injector.get('ctrl');
         });*/
    });

    it('Foo == bar ?', function() {
        expect(control.foo).toEqual('Bar');
    });

    // 10 other functions will use control same as above
});
```

Comment: When I did it I get a `TypeError: currentSpec.queue is undefined in /../../mock.js (line 1651)` after the `module('myApp')` line.

Comment: I am not sure what is `mock.js` and where is it referred. Also make sure `ctrl` is actually injectable. Generally, `$injector` in used to get a provider which can also be replaced by following the convention of underscores as `_$controller_` while injecting. So I would say I am bit skeptical about `ctrl`. Can you post the actual code under test and expand the context of the test case.

Comment: Mock.js is the [Angular-mock.js](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ngMock/angular-mocks.js) file.

Comment: `Ctrl` is a service. I create it with the `factory` function (I edited my question with it's code declaration)

Comment: See update to my answer. mark `_ctrl_` or use of `$injector`.